# how to parse nested json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a Json data which looks like

```
   [{
       "IncidentDate": "11/11/2014",
       "ComputerHits": [{
           "Computer": "abc",
           "Hits": 1
       }, {
           "Computer": "contoso-cscoISE-syslg",
           "Hits": 27
       }]
   }, {
       "IncidentDate": "11/12/2014",
       "ComputerHits": [{
           "Computer": "abc",
           "Hits": 9
       }, {
           "Computer": "contoso-cscoISE-syslg",
           "Hits": 66
       }]
   }]
```

How do i parse them into a array in javascript like its is separated based on date

```
abc= [{Hits:1},{Hits:9}]

contoso-cscoISE-syslg = [{Hits:27},{Hits:66}]
```

for adding them into a jqx chart , can anyone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote this up, which will segregate the Hits and give you.

```js
function custom_parser(A)
{
 var one = {};
 var two = {}; 
 for(var i = 0; i<A.length ; i++)
  {
    var current = A[i];
    var comp = current.ComputerHits;
    //comp is an array
    if(comp[0].Computer in one)
    {
      one[comp[0].Computer].push(comp[0].Hits);
    } 
    else
    {
      one[comp[0].Computer] = [comp[0].Hits];
    }
    if(comp[1].Computer in two)
    {
      two[comp[1].Computer].push(comp[1].Hits);
    } 
    else
    {
      two[comp[1].Computer] = [comp[1].Hits];
    }
  }
 return {one:one,two:two};
}

var B = [{
       "IncidentDate": "11/11/2014",
       "ComputerHits": [{
           "Computer": "abc",
           "Hits": 1
       }, {
           "Computer": "contoso-cscoISE-syslg",
           "Hits": 27
       }]
   }, {
       "IncidentDate": "11/12/2014",
       "ComputerHits": [{
           "Computer": "abc",
           "Hits": 9
       }, {
           "Computer": "contoso-cscoISE-syslg",
           "Hits": 66
       }]
   }];

var C = custom_parser(B);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(C);
```

```html
<div id = "output"></div>
```

Comment: You do realize this is exactly what he didn't want?

Comment: @SZenC I am sorry, I do not follow, he wanted to extract the Hits against Computer name, please tell me what is inconsistent with what he asked?

Comment: Thank you lots @Aravind but the Computer hits is not of fixed size it may contain even more than 2 computers , it would fail in this case .

Comment: @JitheshChandra: You can extend this idea easily for variable lengths, try it. Just loop over the entries. If you cannot get it to work, you can always ask here.

Answer (score 1):

To parse a JSON-string to a JS-object, use JSON.parse as follows;

```
var obj=JSON.parse(str)
```

After that you should be able to reformat to whatever you want.

---

For your exact aplication, we'll go over this step by step,
1.  Parse your string to an object

```
var obj=JSON.parse(str);
```

2.  Iterate over your values

```
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
  for(var j=0;j<obj[i]["ComputerHits"].length;j++){
    //Here will go some more code
  }
}
```

3.  Now add the value to the right variable

```
window[obj[i]["ComputerHits"][j]["Computer"]].push({Hits:obj[i]["ComputerHits"][j]["Hits"]})
```

Now all together;

```
var obj=JSON.parse(str);
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
  for(var j=0;j<obj[i]["ComputerHits"].length;j++){
        window[obj[i]["ComputerHits"][j]["Computer"]].push({Hits:obj[i]["ComputerHits"][j]["Hits"]})
  }
}
```

Comment: The question appears to be misusing the term "parse" to mean "munge", so this doesn't actually answer it. It also doesn't say that the JSON is in a string in the first place.

Comment: That's true, but that's something application-specific. He should be able to do that on his own.

Comment: i am very new to json , javascript , how do i add them into arrays based on name of the computer

Comment: @SZenC — You can say the same thing about parsing JSON. Heck, parsing JSON is just a single function call so it requires less googling and even less thought than munging does.